# For filtering the time what can i do in firebase realtime database?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, time, filter

I wanted to get data from firebase realtime database in the last 10 minutes continously, when i send data to firebase realtime firebase. I tried many ways but it didn t work.

Query

```
query=database.getReference("handler").child("first").orderByChild("time").startAt(start).endAt(finish);query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()...
```

Comment: Why do you say it didn't work? What are the values of `start` and `end`? Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can start at "10 minutes ago", calculated when you're creating the query, and maintain your own timer(s) to implement the "only last 10 minutes" logic of your app.

For example, if you receive a child that is 8 minutes old, add a timer to "forget" that child after 2 minutes. If a child is already given to you more than 10 minutes old (if your query has been running for a while, you will still receive older children, if they're written in the database later), just ignore it.

If performance isn't an issue, you can simply run a check every few seconds to remove all items that are more than 10 minutes old at that point.

You might find it easier to do this with child event listeners instead of value event listeners (so that old children aren't given to you repeatedly on every change).

If you plan to keep the query active for long periods of time, you might want to restart it, to stop receiving much older children.

If you have access to the Cloud Functions of the project, plus you don't need much precision, plus the path you're reading from is common among all your users, you might try something else: Schedule a Cloud Function (every 1 or 2 minutes) to maintain a different path that will have only the items that are roughly up to 10 minutes old, and have the Android clients read from that path.

Docs for scheduling functions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions